# How to display a pandas datafarme in tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I created a pandas dataframe from a csv file in python. How do I display this dataframe in a tkinter window.

```
import pandas as pd
methods = pd.read_csv('metode.csv')
methods = methods.drop(methods.columns[[0]], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of creating a csv file with square roots; reading the the csv and plotting it in tkinter. To capture the matplotlib figure you have to use `FigureCanvasTkAgg` and link the mpl plot with the tkinter figure with `ax=tk_ax` as in the below example.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# create the csv file with square roots
squareroots = [(i, i**0.5) for i in range(0, 100)]
squareroot_df = pd.DataFrame(squareroots, columns=['i', 'i^0.5'])
squareroot_df.to_csv('temp_squareroots.csv', index=False)

# set up the tkinter GUI
root = tk.Tk()
fig, tk_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
mpl_plot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
mpl_plot.get_tk_widget().pack()

# read the csv file
square_roots_df = pd.read_csv('temp_squareroots.csv')

# plot the values in the data frame and invert the x-axis
mpl_ax = square_roots_df.plot(x='i', y='i^0.5', color='firebrick', ax=tk_ax)
mpl_ax.invert_xaxis()

root.mainloop()
```

In any case it is just a lot easier to just plot in matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squareroots = [(i, i**0.5) for i in range(0, 100)]
squareroot_df = pd.DataFrame(squareroots, columns=['i', 'i^0.5'])
squareroot_df.to_csv('temp_squareroots.csv', index=False)

square_roots_df = pd.read_csv('temp_squareroots.csv')

ax = square_roots_df.plot(x='i', y='i^0.5', color='firebrick')
ax.invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

*Note I added `mpl_ax.invert_xaxis()` just to show you can adjust your plot manipulating the `mpl_ax` object. (see [Matplotlib documentation)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/)*